# import Csv file Oledb C#

Tags: c#, csv, oledb

Hi please can anyone give me solution to this problem,i have to import csv file using c# but i have this problem in this screenshot
[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1z6v.png)

the separate betwenn column is ',' but in the data there is a rows tha contains ".

Comment: Please read the [help] and in particular [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Mohamed, I cannot see your screenshot, but can point you toward generic lists and creating a class to represent data. You will need to add references from the "Project" menu.

- Microsoft.VisualBasic
- System.Configuration
- WindowsBase

I am including code from a snippet of code where I was doing that:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;

namespace CsvToListExp
{
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // HARD_CODED FOR EXAMPLE ONLY - TO BE RETRIEVED FROM APP.CONFIG IN REAL PROGRAM
        string hospPath = @"C:\\events\\inbound\\OBLEN_COB_Active_Inv_Advi_Daily_.csv";
        string vendPath = @"C:\\events\\outbound\\Advi_OBlen_Active_Inv_Ack_Daily_.csv";

        List<DenialRecord> hospList = new List<DenialRecord>();
        List<DenialRecord> vendList = new List<DenialRecord>();
        //List<DenialRecord> hospExcpt = new List<DenialRecord>();  // Created at point of use for now
        //List<DenialRecord> vendExcpt = new List<DenialRecord>();  // Created at point of use for now

        using (TextFieldParser hospParser = new Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(hospPath))
        {
            hospParser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
            hospParser.SetDelimiters(",");
            hospParser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = false;
            hospParser.TrimWhiteSpace = true;

            while (!hospParser.EndOfData)
            {

                try
                {
                    string[] row = hospParser.ReadFields();
                    if (row.Length <= 7)
                    {
                        DenialRecord dr = new DenialRecord(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6]);
                        hospList.Add(dr);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    // do something
                    Console.WriteLine("Error is:  {0}", e.ToString());
                }
            }
            hospParser.Close();
            hospParser.Dispose();
        }


        using (TextFieldParser vendParser = new Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(vendPath))
        {
            vendParser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
            vendParser.SetDelimiters(",");
            vendParser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = false;
            vendParser.TrimWhiteSpace = true;

            while (!vendParser.EndOfData)
            {
                try
                {
                    string[] row = vendParser.ReadFields();
                    if (row.Length <= 7)
                    {
                        DenialRecord dr = new DenialRecord(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6]);
                        vendList.Add(dr);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    // do something
                    Console.WriteLine("Error is:  {0}", e.ToString());
                }
            }
            vendParser.Close();
            vendParser.Dispose();
        }

        // Compare the lists each way for denials not in the other source
        List<DenialRecord> hospExcpt = hospList.Except(vendList).ToList();
        List<DenialRecord> vendExcpt = vendList.Except(hospList).ToList();
    }
}
}
```

Google TestFieldParser and look at the methods, properties and constructors. It is very versatile, but runs slowly due to the layers it goes through. It has the ability to set the delimiter, handle fields wrapped in quotes, trim whitespace and many more.

Comment: My Problem is group by in CSV file and can't use linq because i work with framework 2.0